# Password protect a site on Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a prototyped web app that I need to deploy. However I don't want everyone to be able to see it, I need access to be password protected. Additionally I haven't yet properly secured the back-end.

If I host with Amazon EC2 is it possible to password protect access to a website? If so, then will this also solve the problem of an unsecured back-end?